# get link in google map info box

Tags: google-maps

how do get different link of "send to friend", "print map", and "get direction" link in the marker info box related to that marker.

Is there any API for that to get this type links.??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing explicit in the Google Maps API that will show the maps.google.com InfoWindow , you will have to build that functionality into your own [GInfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindow).  For the functionality you describe, you could do the following:

- *send to friend* - Some server side code to email your site URl to a user specified email address?
- *print map* - Link to a cut down page that displays a [Google Static Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) image (for the equivalent location).  The various browsers will do a better, more predictable job of printing an image than they will a Google Map DIV.
- *get direction* - You can use the [GDirections](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections) object to GeoCode to addresses and display the driving directions between those two points (on the map and with instructions).